# Converting and clipping nc4 files into raster file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mesh

Currently I am working on organizing the NASA's Gravity Recovery and Climate Experiment (GRACE) data with QGIS 3.10 and wish to clip it with the state boundary and rasterize its data so that I can do raster calculation.

[image]

It cannot be opened as a raster so I have to use "add Mesh Layer" to open it. I tried Crayfish to edit it but it failed to rasterize (with oversized pixel).

How I can generate the raster with the state boundary of my choice?